# Xorg is using 100% CPU with 15.04

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, 15.04, nvidia-optimus, ubuntu-drivers

Since I upgraded to 15.04 everything is horribly slow, with Xorg using 100% CPU. Can't find any reason in any log file. I have

```
   lspci
   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
   00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
   00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
   00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
   00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d5)
   00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
   00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
   01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
   07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
   09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
   0f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Anyone sees the same? And found a fix? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add "lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2" instead of "lspci"

Comment: Take a look at the log file of Xorg: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
glxinfo |grep string
```

If you get this

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

Then, it looks like I had exactly the same problem: the intel cpu-integrated graphics didn't use intel drivers. I fixed it with the following:

1. Be sure you have installed intel proprietary drivers. In case you have the drivers installed - jump to step 2, in case you don't, go to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads and download "Graphics Installer 1.0.8 for Ubuntu* 14.10" (they currently don't have the version for 15.04, but this version also works fine), install it with

   ```
   dpkg -i name_of_the_downloaded_file.deb
   ```

   The installer of the driver itself won't work, because it checks for Ubuntu version in `/etc/lsb-release`, so save your original `/etc/lsb-release` somewhere and change the file to this:

   ```
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10"
   ```

   Then run the installer:

   ```
   intel-linux-graphics-installer
   ```

   And install the driver (next, next...)

   Now, don't forget to replace back the `/etc/lsb-release` with your saved copy.
2. Edit the grub config

   ```
   vim /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Find

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."
   ```

   And remove "nomodeset" from this line, because if it's set - it will prevent the driver from loading. Save the file and run

   ```
   update-grub
   reboot
   ```

   That's all. It should work fine now.

Comment: This is a VERY bad solution. In many ways.

Comment: Could you explain why? I know it works and there is an open bug for this without any solution... I give a working solution and you say it's bad. OK, I will delete it, no problem... Did you have this problem? Do you know the OS becomes unusable with this bug?It was my first and only post, I use this website for years to get answers and never had any activity here, so just to write the solution I registered, spent my time writing it instead of writing code and you say it's bad. Not good experience, really.

Comment: 1. OP has hybrid graphics with Nvidia. 2. It is not good to change release. 3. Intel installer is not good to install. And many more. Everything is wrong.

Comment: 1. I have hybrid graphics too. With Nvidia. I'm not blind and I see what the OP has.
2. It's a way to install proprietary graphics driver from Intel (until they release the new version for 15.04).
3. I use Intel drivers for a long time and they work fine. I don't see any reason not to use Intel original proprietary driver.

Comment: There is no Intel 'proprietary' driver. They are all open source. I won't argue.

Comment: OK. You win. Here's my new answer: the OP should wait half a year until 1) Intel releases driver for 15.04; OR 2) Ubuntu releases update that fixes the bug. The OP waited for a month already and probably using some other distribution already anyway, because it's unusable with xorg using 100% of CPU.

Comment: @olegk: I also have the NVidia hybrid crap and Ubuntu still hasn't fixed the bug. When Xorg and compiz start eating up to 80% of CPU, nothing but a restart solves it.

Comment: I also have the NVidia hybrid crap and Ubuntu still hasn't fixed the bug. When Xorg and compiz start eating up to 80% of CPU, nothing but a restart solves it. In the meantime "Graphics Installer XXX for Ubuntu*" was changed to "xf86-video-intel".

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution, it's great, I could solve my problem with this https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/472406,, then you must update the kernel and to do in terminal sudo update-grub and reboot,, then you have a PC without problems

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.